# Why some web-page can open popup directly while others need the user to confirm before opening? (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popupwindow

Say I want one of my web pages to be able to open a popup window without prompting users.

I know it's reasonable to ask the user to agree. But I noticed that some website can just open a popup without asking the user's permission. I don't have some exact example for now but I think most of the `<button>`/`<a>` to trigger a Facebook or Twitter share is like this.

How can some website has to ask while some other website hasn't?

Comment: I presume you mean dubious sites that open adult ads and/or try to install malware. They basically have a team of motivated programmers who're searching for loopholes in browsers security but, in general, they normally just open then as response to user clicks, so the browser doesn't see a reason to prevent it.

Comment: What if there's no user click? It'll never be able to open a popup?

Comment: Ideally, not with a modern browser unless user has granted permission. But, as I said, they're always seeking security holes and figuring out tricks.

Answer (score 0):

A window.open(url) would generally open a new window/ tab ( depending on what params you pass to it). I'm really not sure when a website asks for a confirmation before opening a popup.  A particular example would really help.